# How to highlight header column on mouse hover?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, hover

I have an owner drawn header of a ListView control. If the header is not owner drawn we have a nice hover effect when mouse is on one of the header's columns. After I made header columns owner drawn I have to take care of the hover effect myself.

In order to catch it I monitor `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message within header window and when I get this message I redraw the column of a header with changed background first and on top of that I draw text and other necessary graphics. There is just one but... The font of a text becomes **bold**.

You can see it below. First header is mine, and second header is from Windows explorer with hover effect on Date modified column.

[image]

Why does the font suddenly becomes bold?
Is this the right way to implement hover effect? Maybe I missed some Header specific notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In owner draw mode you have to take care of everything including fonts. Don't assume you know what the current DC font is. If you want a specific font you need to select one into the DC before drawing text.

Comment: Yup - That bold font is the default for the DC.  The poster can send a WM_GETFONT to the header control to fetch the proper font.

Comment: Yeap, I used WM_GETFONT message to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved this mystery :) Even though I still don't know why the font used in DrawThemeText function suddenly changed in `WM_MOUSEMOVE` notification. My approach still relies on catching `WM_MOUSEMOVE` event and redrawing the column underneath the mouse pointer. In order not to change the default header font (like in illustration in my question) I used the following code to get and set it:

```
HFONT displayFont = (HFONT)SendMessage( header, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0 ); // gets default header font
SelectObject(hdc, displayFont); // sets device context to use newly found font
```

This solution has at least one drawback: I redraw the Header too frequently (each time mouse moves within header column).